# Applet issues in Firefox 4

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, applet

I add an applet to the html page in my extension. The following line of code raises an exception:

```
    try {
        document.Applet.isActive();
    }
    catch(e) {
        setTimeout(doingSomeThing(),200);
        return;
    }
```

> Error: Attempt to call a default method on object with no invokeDefault method

And after a while:

> TypeError: document.Applet.isActive is not a function

I am testing the extension on different OS and firefox versions for deployment. The above error occurred on Firefox 4.0 on a Mac OS X machine running Java 1.6.0_22.

It tested it with Java version 1.6.0_24 on Mac OS X and it worked fine.

Any ideas regarding this?

**Update:** I am attaching the Java console output on 1.6.0_22

```
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition value null
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,apple.,com.apple.mrj.,com.apple.jdirect.,com.apple.audio.jdirect.,quicktime.internal.,com.sun.medialib.mlib.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
basic: Told clients applet is started
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_22
Using JRE version 1.6.0_22-b04-307-10M3261 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM User home directory = /Users/tomrTrace level set to 5: all… completed.
basic: Starting applet teardown
basic: Finished applet teardown
basic: Told clients applet is started
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Have a look over [Detect if an Applet is ready](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0176.html)  It is more complicated that throwing a single line of JS into the HTML at some random point.

If looking over that document does not sort the problem for you, I suggest you prepare & post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html), and the URL to a place where we can see the applet working/failing.